# AvaloniaUI - How to choose folder

Tags: c#, wpf, avaloniaui

I am using AvaloniaUI https://avaloniaui.net/docs/

I have researched their docs but it seems I can not find how can I make button which when pressed is forcing you to choose a folder.

Is it even possible and if so how, is there any example ?

Answer (score 0):

I toyed with AvaloniaUI some time ago, got it working under Windows and struggled getting it working under Mac.

Nevertheless, I've seen your other question where you seem to get the dialog opened. Still, for the future:

In your XAML you place a button in a place you please:
`<Button Content="Choose folder..." Margin="3" Name="FolderButton" />`

Perhaps there is another way of getting it working, the following worked for me:
In your code you need to create a variable that represents your button:
`private Button _folderButton;`
In your constructor or in your `InitializeComponent()` method you find the button from XAML and assign it to your variable:
`_folderButton = this.FindControl<Button>("FolderButton");`
You also assign an event handler for `Click` event:
`_folderButton.Click += FolderButtonClick;`
You can immediately add the unsubscribe in your destructor:
`_folderButton.Click -= FolderButtonClick;`

Now you provide an event handler declaration and implementation:

```
public void FolderButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

You may use http://avaloniaui.net/api/Avalonia.Controls/OpenFolderDialog/ - as you've already found out in your other question.

This even handler can be made `async` if you have any `await` operations inside.

I hope this helps.